# Node.js and npm do not work in Windows Terminal's Ubuntu window

Tags: node.js, npm

On Windows machine I have installed node.j by running installer. Node.js and npm show up in a Command Prompt, but they dont show up in Windows Terminal under Ubuntu window tab. When running `node -v` it suggest to install it and for `npm -v` gives not found.

How to make them working in Windows Terminal' Ubuntu window? Does it need to be installed separately in the Ubuntu?

Comment: you mean the linux subsystem for windows? If so: yes, you would need to install that separately, However, the real question is why you'd need LSW at all, Node and NPM run perfectly fine in Windows, and almost every `npm`-provided tool is cross-platform compatible. There should not be a reason to need LSW's bash.

Comment: Im following React online course where Linux terminal is used and since some Linux commands do not work in CMD, I want to run node.js from Windows Terminal where Im using Ubuntu. 
Wasnt the reason for Windows Terminal so user will have Linux like terminal on Windows OS?

Comment: it was, but that doesn't mean _you_ need it. If you install `git` on windows, it can install the standard unix toolchain for you as part of the `git` install, which you should absolutely do if you're actually developing on Windows. The idea that a react tutorial would be for _any_ specific OS is kind of crazy: there is nothing about the Node ecosystem that is locked to any particular OS.

Comment: Having said that, use https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm to install Node in any \*n\*x environments (linux, unix, macos, LSW, etc)

Comment: The idea is not about react tutorial to be specific for OS, but just to able to run linux command on command line.

Comment: Right, which `git` already installs for you, so those shouldn't matter: if you've installed `git` from the official installer on https://git-scm.com, you can (and should) tell it to install the standard unix tools too, and then `cp`, `ls`, `mv`, `touch`, `cat`, etc. etc. all natively work in Windows, making "you need Linux" simply not true.